# Exchange API missing from Supported Legacy APIs

Tags: azure-active-directory, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am currently trying to follow the steps listed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

However to add the delegated permission I need (EWS.AccessAsUser.All), the author suggests you should
"Select Add a permission. On the Request API permissions page, select Exchange under Supported legacy APIs."
This worked a few months back when I tried it in a prototype but the whole Exchange API under the "Legacy APIs" section appears to have been removed.

I can not find any mention of this anywhere on GitHub, SO or MSDN.

Please note some of the functionality I need is not yet supported in Microsoft Graph so using that API is not currently an option for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I found out to my surprise that now you will need to search it within the "APIs my organization uses" by the name : Office 365 Exchange Online. You will be able to assign the necessary permission afterwards.

Comment: For the record: typing "exchange" in the search box will not find it in the "APIs my organization uses" list (?!), but "office" will.